# Pascal Bubble Sort

Tags: pascal, bubble-sort

I have a project where the program must accept 10 words and display the words in descending order (alphabetical order from Z-A) 
using bubble sorting.
Here's what I know so far:
    Program sample; 
    uses crt;

```
TYPE 
    no._list=ARRAY(1...10)OF REAL; 
CONST 
    no.:no._list=(20.00,50.50.35.70....);
VAR 
    x:INTEGER; 
    small:REAL; 

BEGIN clrscr: 
    small:=no.(1); 
    FOR x:=2 TO 10 DO 
       IF small>number(x); 
       writeln('Smallest value in the array of no.s is',small:7:2); 
END
```

I really don't know how to do this though and could use some help.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific problems are you having?  We're here to help with questions, not do your homework for you.

Comment: oh.. sorry.. our teacher only taught us bubble sorting number.. It's actually our project. she didn't actually discuss this thing yet she gave it as a project.

Comment: If you know how to bubble sort numbers all you have to do is rewrite the place that compares numbers to compare strings instead. Oh, and change data types from number to string.

Comment: oh.... I get it THANKS :)) but still confusing

Comment: This is so funny.. had the OP not mentioned homework, we all would've written the routine...lol

Comment: @JohnEasley, Yeah that was exactly what I was thinking. at least he is honest :) +1 for that.

Comment: BTW, in Delphi "Demos\Threads` directory you have implementations of 3 kinds of sort algorithms (Quick sort is actually faster than Bubble Sort). So, you kill 3 birds plus you can learn Threading as well. amaze your teacher with that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video by Alister Christie on Bubble sort describing the principle :
http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=64&Itemid=1

The algorithm in Pascal can be found @ http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: btw just Googling would have given you the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function BubbleSort( list: TStringList ): TStringList;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  temp: string;
begin
  // bubble sort
  for i := 0 to list.Count - 1 do begin
    for j := 0 to ( list.Count - 1 ) - i do begin
      // Condition to handle i=0 & j = 9. j+1 tries to access x[10] which
      // is not there in zero based array
      if ( j + 1 = list.Count ) then
        continue;
      if ( list.Strings[j] > list.Strings[j+1] ) then begin
        temp              := list.Strings[j];
        list.Strings[j]   := list.Strings[j+1];
        list.Strings[j+1] := temp;
      end; // endif
    end; // endwhile
  end; // endwhile
  Result := list;
end;
```